# Swift Firebase Storage How to retrieve image with unknow name(NSUUID)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am making a function to retrieve the url as the user Image. However, my upload image name function created by NSUUID. Therefore, I would not know what is the name of each user profile picture. How could I improve my code to get the user imgae for every user instead of hard coding the img name?

```
func getUserProfilePic(){
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let profilePath = refStorage.child("\(uid)").child("profilePic/xxxxx.jpg") // xxxxx = NSUUID

profilePath.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
  if (error != nil) {
    print("got no pic")
  } else {

    let profilePic: UIImage! = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.imageV.image = profilePic
    print("got pic")
  }
}
}
```

The path is uid/profilePic/--<-file name->--

upload function

```
  func uploadingPhoto(){
let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
let imgName = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".jpg"
let filePath = refStorage.child("\(uid!)/profilePic/\(imgName)")
var imageData = NSData()
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic.image!, 0.8)!

let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"

let uploadTask = filePath.putData(imageData, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
  if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}else{
    let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
    let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let userRef = self.dataRef.child("user").child(uid!)
    userRef.updateChildValues(["photoUrl": downloadURL])
    print("alter the new profile pic and upload success")

  }

}
```

Comment: show upload image function code...

Comment: @AaronSaunders updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be two ways to go about this :-

1.) Store the Firebase Storage path of users `profile_picture` in your Firebase database and retrieve every time before you start downloading your profile picture.

2.) Store the file path in `CoreData` every time your user uploads a profile picture and hit that `path` every time to get file_Path to where you stored that user's `profile_pic` .

Storing the path :-

```
func uploadSuccess(metadata : FIRStorageMetadata , storagePath : String)
{   
    print("upload succeded!")
    print(storagePath)

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(storagePath, forKey: "storagePath.\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)")
    //Setting storagePath : (file path of your profile pic in firebase) to a unique key for every user "storagePath.\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)"
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

 }
```

Retrieving your path, Every time you start downloading your image :-

```
let storagePathForProfilePic = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("storagePath.\((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!)") as? String
```

Note :- i am using `currentUser` ID, you can use USER SPECIFIC id ,if you want to download multiple users profile pics, all you need to do is put their `uid` in place.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, do you recommend to store every user details in NSUserDefault?

Comment: No just these file path's that you have to search in your Backend... rest is up to you...

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend using Firebase Storage and the Firebase Realtime Database together to store that UUID -> URL mapping, and to "list" files. The [Realtime Database will handle offline use cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities) like Core Data as well, so there's really no reason to futz with Core Data or `NSUserDefaults`. Some code to show how these pieces interact is below:

Shared:

```
// Firebase services
var database: FIRDatabase!
var storage: FIRStorage!
...
// Initialize Database, Auth, Storage
database = FIRDatabase.database()
storage = FIRStorage.storage()
```

Upload:

```
let fileData = NSData() // get data...
let storageRef = storage.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
storageRef.putData(fileData).observeStatus(.Success) { (snapshot) in
  // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get it's download URL
  let downloadURL = snapshot.metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
  // Write the download URL to the Realtime Database
  let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles/myFile")
  dbRef.setValue(downloadURL)
}
```

Download:

```
let dbRef = database.reference().child("myFiles")
dbRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
  // Get download URL from snapshot
  let downloadURL = snapshot.value() as! String
  // Create a storage reference from the URL
  let storageRef = storage.referenceFromURL(downloadURL)
  // Download the data, assuming a max size of 1MB (you can change this as necessary)
  storageRef.dataWithMaxSize(1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
    // Do something with downloaded data...
  })
})
```

For more information, see [Zero to App: Develop with Firebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE), and it's [associated source code](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd), for a practical example of how to do this.