# check for updates on Firebase Storage and replace the old content?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

what i wanna do is every time i open the app or there is new data changed from the server the data saved locally should be updated.

i have used this code to download and save the data locally

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if book?.bookPath !=  book?.bookPath {
        print("HERE \(book?.bookPath)")
        loadReader(filePaht: (book?.bookPath)!)

    } else {

        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let strName = book?.id
        let filePath = "\(documentsPath)/"+strName!+".pdf"
        let fileManager = FileManager.default

        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
            return;
        }           
        let reference = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL: (self.book?.bookURL)!)
         downloadTask =  reference.data(withMaxSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil) {

            } else {

                if ((try! data?.write(to: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath, isDirectory: false))) != nil) {
                    self.db.upDate(id: (self.book?.id)!, bookPath: filePath)

                    self.loadReader(filePaht: filePath)
                }
            }
        }
        downloadTask.observe(.resume) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download resumed, also fires when the download starts
        }

        downloadTask.observe(.pause) { (snapshot) -> Void in
            // Download paused

        }
        downloadTask.observe(.progress) { (snapshot) -> Void in

            }


        downloadTask.observe(.success) { (snapshot) -> Void in

        }

        downloadTask.observe(.failure) { (snapshot) -> Void in

        }

    }
}

    }
}
```

what happens here is the data gets downloaded locally on the phone and when i change it on firebase it doesn't change on the phone itself after being downloaded

Comment: `.observe(.value` is listening for changed in data and gets called everytime data is changed ... your completion handler from the request will be called everytime this happens

Comment: yeah but it doesn't do that when the data is already downloaded and saved locally on the phone. what if i wanna change it to whatever was updated on the server. so lets say picture 1 was downloaded for the server and i deleted picture 1 from the server and replaced it with picture 2. how do i delete picture 1 from the phone itself and replace it with picture 2 or atleast make the user download it again

Comment: if you are referring to `FirebaseStorage` then it works in a different way, if you are referring to `FirebaseDatabase` then every time some value changes in the data in the database the completion handler is called, this means `arrayBooks` will have the new data

Comment: yes sorry i showed the wrong code and i am gonna be updating it soon. firebaseDatabase works fine. i am referring to FirebaseStorage

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Storage doesn't sync files the same way the Firebase Realtime Database does.

You want to use the Database to sync file changes, as shown in a bunch of other SO posts (like this one: [Swift Firebase Storage How to retrieve image with unknow name(NSUUID)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38937740/swift-firebase-storage-how-to-retrieve-image-with-unknow-namensuuid/38964617#38964617), which has the exact code you want), as well as our I/O talk [Zero to App](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAsvwy1-oxE) and it's [source code](https://gist.github.com/mcdonamp/cc45567cd95ba2a62017cb21e891effd)

Alternatively, you can just store the `etag` or `md5` hash locally and do a metadata fetch, check to see if they're the same, and if they aren't, fetch the new one.